# How to configure Spartacus and Accelerator based Storefront Side by Side? (External Routes)

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In the Spartacus documentation (https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/external-routes/#page-title) it is mentioned that it is possible to configure Spartacus to deliver certain routes directly from the backend and therefore move somehow step by step from Accelerator to Spartacus Storefront.

Nevertheless I don't really understand how this should work and how I have to configure it.

My current environment:

- Host Entry 127.0.0.1 electronics.local
- A Hybris 2011 Spartacus Demo Setup (Spartacus 3.2.0)
- Running Accelerator Storefront under https://electronics.local:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/
- Running Spartacus under http://localhost:4200 (Removed BaseSite & co properties)
- I configured the routing in the following way to exclude cart and Hybris style product pages

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        BaseStorefrontModule,
        SpartacusFeaturesModule,
        SpartacusConfigurationModule,
        ConfigModule.withConfig({
          routing: {
            internal: [
              '/**',
              '!/cart',
              '!/**/p/**'
            ]
          }
        }),
      ],
      exports: [BaseStorefrontModule]
    })
    export class SpartacusModule { }
```

In order to achieve that both storefronts would be under the same domain, I would need to setup an apache virtual host or something (let's say electronics.local pointing to both 9002 and 4200) but how shall be detected to which port the request shall go when coming from the outside? As I understand the request should always be deliverd from the Spartacus App.

Furthermore my configuration does not seem to work. My test Url's are still handled by Spartacus.

- http://localhost:4200/cart
- http://localhost:4200/p/832382

Any more detailed documentation or a configuration example would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I had to add ExternalRoutesModule.forRoot() in spartacus.module.ts for the code to work in the SPA. It was not added by default in the current Spartacus version.

I used the following Apache Config which seemed to work. Nevertheless the switch between SPA and non-SPA took quite long. Perhaps I have to optimize the HTTPS, HTTP stuff and the paths for the accelerator based storefront. But nevertheless is works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName electronics.local

RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on

# Local hack because of self signed certificate
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

RewriteRule "/cart" "https://electronics.local:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/de/cart" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/cart" "https://electronics.local:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/de/cart"

RewriteRule "/yacceleratorstorefront/(.*)" "https://electronics.local:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/yacceleratorstorefront/" "https://electronics.local:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/"

RewriteRule "/(.*)"     "http://localhost:4200/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:4200/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a proxy with path based routing to two different backends.

```
www.domain.com/{site}/{lang}/{currency}/cart    -> route to Accelerator Storefront
www.domain.com/{site}/{lang}/{currency}/**/p/** -> route to Accelerator Storefront
www.domain.com/{site}/{lang}/{currency}/*       -> route to Spartacus
```

When your route config in Spartacus is working properly, it should do a reload with the external url, then the request go to the proxy and this should route you to the Accelerator backend.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the edited question, one has to define an web proxy that does a correct rewrite for the configured external routes.

The route in Spartacus did not work because of a missing import of the ExternalRoutes module.